# Local XML file to populate TableViewController

Tags: ios, xml, swift, tableview

I have a stored XML file in swift that I want to get data from and view in my tableviewcontroller however all I can seem to find is ways to get this data from a URL..

Example:

```
 let urlString = NSURL(string: “http://www.blubrry.com/feeds/onorte.xml")
  let rssUrlRequest:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:urlString!)
  let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

  NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(rssUrlRequest, queue: queue) {
(response, data, error) -> Void in
self.xmlParser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
self.xmlParser.delegate = self
self.xmlParser.parse()
}
```

Is there anyway I can simply declare where my XML file is instead of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

NSURL can be used for local files as well:

> URL objects are the preferred way to refer to local files. Most objects that read data from or write data to a file have methods that accept an NSURL object instead of a pathname as the file reference. For example, you can get the contents of a local file URL as an NSString object by calling the stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error: method, or as an NSData object by calling the dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: method.

Comment: would this be how you do it ?? func beginParsing() { let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL //let dataFolderURL = bundleURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("data") let fileURL = NSURL(string: ppl.xml, relativeToURL: bundleURL) print("(/Users/hatty/Desktop/ppl.xml)") parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: fileURL!)! parser.delegate = self parser.parse() } @dbn

Comment: That looks appropriate if your file is indeed in your bundle. Might want to use if-let to unwrap the optional just in case the file does not exist.